# What directory are spooled print files written to in Windows XP?

Tags: windows-xp, print-spooler

I just need to know where the temporary files are written to when a printer is configured to spool before printing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default system-wide print spooling directory in Windows XP is `%SystemRoot%\SYSTEM32\SPOOL\PRINTERS`.

According to [MS Help & Support](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/314105), to view (or change) the default print spooling directory:

1. Go to Printers and Faxes in Control Panel.
2. On the File menu, click Server Properties, and then switch to the Advanced tab.
3. The spooling directory can be seen in the Spool Folder textbox. To change the directory, just type the new path that you want to use, and click OK.

To set spooling directories for individual printers involves editing the Windows registry:

1. Add/change the REG_SZ value in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Print\Printers\*specific printer*\SpoolDirectory.
2. Make sure that the directory you specified exists and has [appropriate user permissions](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/137503/EN-US/).
3. Stop and restart the Spooler Service, under Services in Control Panel.

Comment: Thanks; that what I needed to know - I can print again (after relocating the spooler directory out of my locked-down Windows directory).